# Task.FromResult returns null c# Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I've got a unit test which gets the content from the method GetClubMenuUrl. It currently returns null on the line `"var result = await sut.GetClubMenuUrl(testkey);"`I'm assuming the Returns method is not implemented correctly but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
[Theory]
[AutoDomainData]
public async Task When_GetClubMenuURL_WithCorrectKey_ContentReturnedAsync(
    [Frozen] Mock<IClubService> serviceMock,
    ClubService sut,
    int testkey,
    Task<TypedResponseDto<List<ClubMenuResponseDto>>> someData)
{
    
    // Arrange
    serviceMock
        .Setup(c => c.GetClubMenuUrl(It.IsAny<int>()))
         serviceMock.Setup(c => c.GetVenueMenuUrl(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new TypedResponseDto<List<ClubMenuResponseDto>>());

    // Act
    var result = await sut.GetClubMenuUrl(testkey);

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(result.Data, someData.Result.Data);
}
```

This is the method I'm trying to test.

```
        public async Task<TypedResponseDto<List<ClubMenuResponseDto>>> GetClubMenuUrl(int clubId)
        {
            var venue = await _context.Restaurant.Where(w => w.ClubId == clubId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (club== null)
            {
                throw new ApiException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, $"Clubwith {clubId} id does not exist");
            }

            var result = await _Service.GetBusinessMenuUrl(club);

            return new TypedResponseDto<List<ClubMenuResponseDto>>
            {
                Data = result
            };
        }
```

Comment: How should I be going about to test that method?

Comment: Deleted wrong comment. You may want to [edit] the post to show how you setup your test and add tag/info on the testing framework you using.

Comment: I see okay I'll try re think the question I didn't want to make it too long just incase it got down voted and confusing

Comment: Imagine if there was a Moq `returns` method specifically for async methods... we could call it something like `ReturnsAsync`... hmmm...

Comment: haha tried that @IanKemp still gave the same output

Comment: Why are you passing in a `Task<TypedResponseDto<List<ClubMenuResponseDto>>>` instead of just the list? Why is your method not named ending in `async`?

Comment: Because thats the response type I want returned.

Comment: Maybe `await _Service.GetBusinessMenuUrl(club)` indeed returns null? I don't think we have enough info about `_Service`.